# Starting up with Underscore.js (A simple running program)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am a UI/Ux designer worrying to start up with underscore.js. I have used jquery, jquery-ui, and other javascript libraries, where we add the cdn and start up with events and classes to get our work done.

I would like to start up with a simple program with underscore.js but am out of any worthwhile tutorial like in 'w3schools.com' to start up with. Can someone help me out with a simple running program with it?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    //underscore code goes here ... 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: try asking a more precice question. What are you trying to achieve, what have you tried?

Comment: I dont even know how to begin, except that I know cdn. How can I be more precise ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Or, what is it your application should do?

Comment: Start up with underscore.js. Whereever I see node.js, bower, etc. are coming up. I just want a simple underscore program.

Comment: I'm sorry, but http://underscorejs.org/ only provides some methods developers often use. And before you start developing something, you should at least think about what you program schould do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm lazy to set up a JSFiddle to try out something in underscore I just google for underscore jsfiddle [underscore function name]. Google will return you some JSFiddle examples that are (mostly) correctly set up and you already have something to try out/modify:

```
_.each(list, iteratee, [context])
```

[_.each](http://jsfiddle.net/tylerbrownhenry/AHEYf/)

```
_.template(templateString, [settings])
```

[_.template](http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/gXx9L/)

Comment: btw, you stated in your question that w3schools.com hosts worthwhile tutorials. Consider learning from more reputable resources: http://www.w3fools.com/